# Commiting Project from One URL to Another using Visual SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

First time i uploaded my project on "://#.#.#.13:#/test" using tortoiseSVN then i deleted this path and made a new one "://#.#.#.17:#/test2" , now i want to commit my all project files to new path using visual svn in visual studio 2010 but it does not gives any option to commit project files to new path.

here is screen shot

[image]

Comment: Is it the same repository? I.e. only URL has changed or it's another repository?

Comment: repository is also changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , After deep researching and thinking about ideas how to relocate Projects URL to new URL i have solved it out. I want to share this to every one so may be in future some one comes to this issue of relocating whole project to new one using tortoise SVN.
Here what i did

1. Simply , right click on Project and click on tortoise SVN icon and then click on option "Relocate" and enter the path of new URL on which you want to commit new changes of project.

here are screen shots of what i did

[image]